# Autogluon's set_model_best not using good folder

Tags: python, prediction

I'm using Autogluon to predict if som text fits on a category

I'm trying to select a model, but when I execute

```
predictor.set_model_best('NeuralNetFastAI_BAG_L2')
```

or any other model, I get the same error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxx/models/NeuralNetFastAI_BAG_L2\\model.pkl'
```

(xxx) is the full path of my project.
The strange thing is all path uses "/" but when try to find the file on the model folder uses "\" (use 2 like tryng to scape special character).
It's like when it try to get the file "model.pkl" not recognise have to enter into a folder...

any idea?

I tried to use several models but with same result. I tryed to put the complete path to the model but I get the error

```
 Model "xxx/models/WeightedEnsemble_L3/model.pkl" is not a valid model to specify as best! Valid models: ['LightGBMXT_BAG_L1', 'LightGBM_BAG_L1', 'RandomForestGini_BAG_L1', 'RandomForestEntr_BAG_L1', 'CatBoost_BAG_L1', 'ExtraTreesGini_BAG_L1', 'ExtraTreesEntr_BAG_L1', 'NeuralNetFastAI_BAG_L1', 'XGBoost_BAG_L1', 'NeuralNetTorch_BAG_L1', 'LightGBMLarge_BAG_L1', 'WeightedEnsemble_L2', 'LightGBMXT_BAG_L2', 'LightGBM_BAG_L2', 'RandomForestGini_BAG_L2', 'RandomForestEntr_BAG_L2', 'CatBoost_BAG_L2', 'ExtraTreesGini_BAG_L2', 'ExtraTreesEntr_BAG_L2', 'NeuralNetFastAI_BAG_L2', 'XGBoost_BAG_L2', 'NeuralNetTorch_BAG_L2', 'LightGBMLarge_BAG_L2', 'WeightedEnsemble_L3']
```

Like don't want the absolute route to the file, only name the model